# retrieve date from SQL into C# gridview

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, gridview, textbox

I've sql database which is connected to c# windows form
in the database there's column with date , data type only date dd/mm/yyyy
and the data inside this column is also saved the same
I've a gridview in the C# which retrieve all the data  into it, it shows the date asin database dd/mm/yyyy
I've a trigger " SelectionChanged" on the grid and it copies the data into textBoxes , but the date always comes with time dd/mm/yyyy tt:mm:ss AM/PM  which is not in the Database at all
what I'm missing ?

checked the datatypein sql, it showed only dd/mm/yyyy no date in datatype or in thedata itself
reconnected the database to the C# application, recreated the gridview

Comment: It doesn't matter what's in the database. In .NET, dates are represented using the `DateTime` type, which contains date and time. If there's no time then it will be zero, i.e. midnight. There is now `DateOnly` in newer versions but that is not yet widely supported. If you only want to work with the date portion then do so. That means specifying a format when displaying the data that includes the date but not the time. Exactly how to do that in your case, we can't tell you, because we don't know exactly what you're doing now. It might require an attribute on your model but who knows?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
dgv.Columns["DateColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```